# Flask test_client: Testing DELETE request with data

Tags: python, unit-testing, flask, werkzeug

I'm trying to test my Flask app using suggestions from http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/testing/, but I couldn't figure out how to test DELETE method with form data.

My delete method looks something like this:

```
from flask.ext.restful import Resource, reqparse 
...
def delete(self):
    self.reqparse.add_argument('arg1', type=str, required=True, location='form')
    args = self.reqparse.parse_args()
    ...
```

I would like to test it with:

```
def setUp(self):
    self.app = myApp.app.test_client()

def test_delete(self):
    rv = self.app.delete('MyEndPoint', data={'arg1', 'val'})
```

But it doesn't work. I also looked at the source code of EnvironBuilder in werkzeug.test but still got no idea how to pass in the data.

Comment: Are you using `.delete('/url/where/my/endpoint/is/mounted', data={})` or `.delete('name.of.my.endpoint', data={})`?  Because the former is what you want (the first argument to `EnvironBuilder` is a URL).

Comment: I'm using the name only, but I don't think it's wrong. See examples in [link](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/testing/). Also, the response shows I'm accessing the right place. It's just I didn't pass in the data correctly.

Answer (score 10):

I just ran into the same issue, and this is basically because Werkzeug's test method does not currently support setting the `content_type` of DELETE requests.

The code [here](https://github.com/mitsuhiko/werkzeug/blob/master/werkzeug/test.py#L379-L387) shows how Werkzeug gets the content type:

```
def _get_content_type(self):
    ct = self.headers.get('Content-Type')
    if ct is None and not self._input_stream:
        if self.method in ('POST', 'PUT', 'PATCH'):
            if self._files:
                return 'multipart/form-data'
            return 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
        return None
    return ct
```

If there's no `content_type`, then the form data never makes it out of the `environ` and into the request, so your Flask server doesn't actually get sent the data.

Ultimately, this is a bug with Werkzeug, as you can craft a `curl` request that uses a DELETE method and also includes form data.  I've submitted a pull request to the Werkzeug repo to address this issue.  Feel free to chime in on github: https://github.com/mitsuhiko/werkzeug/pull/620

**Update**: to actually solve your problem in the mean time, you can get around this by explicitly stating a content type in your request, like so:

```
def test_delete(self):
    rv = self.app.delete('MyEndPoint',
                         data={'arg1', 'val'},
                         headers={'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'})
```

**Update again**: The pull request I've submitted has been reviewed, refined, and merged, and will be included in the 0.10 release of Werkzeug, so hopefully this shouldn't be an issue anymore :)